# Starting from a particular cell every time

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to automate a process using VBA in excel. For this, I have to use a formula to get values from another workbook and paste in a fix set of cells (N4:AK4001). I have recorded a macro to do this. However, the macro is dependent on the selected cell. Only if the selected cell is N4, the macro runs on all the cells, otherwise it would start from the selected cell and leave aside values at the top and left of the selected cell.
Please find below my code and help me try and solve this.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=HLOOKUP(R3C,'[User Menu Log Analysis_2 - Nov 22.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C15:R4000C39,'[User Menu Log Analysis_2 - Nov 22.xlsx]Sheet1'!R[-1]C1,FALSE)"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:X1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:X3998").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(R3C,'[User Menu Log Analysis_2 - Nov 22.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C15:R4000C39,'[User Menu Log Analysis_2 - Nov 22.xlsx]Sheet1'!R[-1]C1,FALSE),"""")"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I am new to VBA and programming in general. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What about  putting `Range("N4").Select` right at the top of the macro?

Comment: if you plan to have the right sheet selected, you could use find and replace to replace ActiveCell with Range("N4"). If you might not have that particular sheet selected you could replace it with thisworkbook.worksheets("sheet1").range("N4") (replace sheet1 with whatever the tab you want it to fix is called)